# Dynamic link ms project to excel and perform calculations

Tags: excel, ms-project

I would like to use excel to calculate ETC and EAC against my budget. I managed to link the project data to my excel file.
However the data is displayed in excel as `10 days`. Excel does not treat this as a number. So doing calculations with the data is not really working.

Any suggestions on how to manipulate this

Comment: As long as dates are formatted correctly, then they can be used in calculations or with calculations. It is possible to add 10 to a given date and get the result of 10 days later.

Comment: Hi Mike, i pull information from an other source to compare actuals. any suggestions on how to convert to a number since the 10 days are formatted as a string and i do not seem to be able to change that